# Zip File Entry has custom file extension. C# claims it cannot open

Tags: c#, .net, file-type

**Solution Found.**

Thanks to everyone helping me, I found out what the root problem was. The .trl file had nothing to do with it. It was the path being created wrong. I was doing "TRLR" + Path, when it should have been "TRLR" + fileName. This was a stupid error on my part, and I apologize for wasting your time, but I appreciate the help!

---

I have a zip file given to us by a 3rd party. In this zip files are custom files. These are just text files with a different extension, which I assume is just to frustrate me.

I'm trying to open this files in my C# application, but it keeps throwing the error that the format is not supported.

Since these are just text files, I feel there must be some way for this to happen.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Code:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(_trailerName))
{
     ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.GetEntry(tableChanged + ".trl");
     Stream ms = entry.Open(); //Here is what's causing the issue.
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms);
     string allLinesRead = reader.ReadToEnd();
     string[] everyCell = allLinesRead.Split('|');
     int numRecords = Convert.ToInt32(everyCell[1]);
     int numChanged = getRecordNum(tableChanged);
     Console.Write(numRecords + "/" + numChanged + " - " + tableChanged);
     if (numChanged != numRecords)
     {
          _errorMessage += "Records updated do not match trailer. (" + numRecords + "/" + numChanged + ") Please check database. Table affected: " + tableChanged + Environment.NewLine;
     }
}
```

Error:

`The given path's format is not supported.`

I know this is specific, but I need advice on what steps I can take to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Open your file in your favorite text editor (like notepad++), does the file start with `PK`?

Comment: It does not. It opens exactly like any other text file would

Comment: Start by opening it with WinZip, and extract all files.

Comment: This will be run every day, and there are over 500 files in each zip file. This will be run on 4 of these files daily. This is meant to be completely automated, and I would rather not use up resources resaving all these files just to change .trl to .txt if I can avoid it.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you rename the extension.  If the file (in a text editor) starts with `PK` its a standard zip file format.  Anything else and you're dealing with a custom format.  To be clear, i'm talking about the zip file, not the contents of the zip.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood. It does begin with PK

Comment: Another silly question, what's in entry. Does it look sane?

Comment: Are you sure that `ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.GetEntry(tableChanged + ".trl");` is coming back with a valid value?

Comment: 07/07/2013  04:51:04 AM|8||0

This is inside one. It contains Date extracted, number of records in db, ???, and number of records deleted. It's delimited by pipes.

Comment: @papagomez, yes it is coming back with a valid value. It's just that when it goes to open the file, it throws an error, since it doesn't recognize the .trl extension.

Comment: Are you getting `InvalidDataException`? [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open.aspx) indicates that you will get that exception if the entry was compressed in a way that is not supported. If that's the case, then you can't use the `ZipArchive` stuff to extract that file.

Comment: `System.NotSupportedException` is the exception being thrown.

Comment: I created a text file with a `.trl` extension, put it in a `zip` file and ran your exact code and it works just fine.  The problem isnt your code.

Comment: Could the problem be encoding or something similar? The files seem to behave just fine as text files, so I can't figure out what could be causing this.
Also, I really appreciate you taking the time to try and reproduce the error

Comment: I tried having it just read the file, without it being in a zip file, and it worked just fine. So, the issue may lie with the zip file

Comment: I found the explanation. Original comment updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native zip functionality of .NET is frequently lacking in terms of the ability to handle and modify zip files created by applications other than the windows zip tool. While the "zip" file is standardized, you still see a decent amount of variation on file headers and attributes.

I would suggest you look into DotNetZip (Ionic), which is a third party library that has very robust capabilities in terms of creating and opening zip files. I've found it to be much more forgiving and capable than the basic functionality that .NET gives you, and the code to open a zip is extremely similar to what you have.

Comment: It can open the zip file just fine, it's the file that is within the zip file that is causing the trouble.

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried opening these files in notepad to ensure the file is actually formatted correctly?

Comment: I have opened in notepad and notepad++ and sublime Text. It opens just fine in all, and shows exactly what I want

Comment: In your code, have you tried fully extracting the file with the zip library and then reading the file as opposed to streaming it from the compressed file? This would help isolate whether the zip library is having an issue with the format of the zip file or not.

Comment: Good idea. I tried that, and it is reading the file just fine. Now I am more confused

Comment: Even stranger, when it tries to read from another application using this exact code, it works flawlessly. Something is going on with my code then. I'm going to see if I can figure it out

Comment: Solution found. I explain in original question.